# Camera Preview and OCR

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-camera, ocr, tesseract

I am new to android development - I'm using Xamarin.

I am trying to write an application that initiates the camera preview, and then constantly scans the incoming frames for text (I am using Xamarin.Tesseract from NuGet).

In other words, I don't want to make the user take a photo and then do the OCR analysis, instead I want them to just point the video camera at some paper with text on it, i'll continually do the OCR analysis until I detect the specific text I'm searching for) at which point I'll give a big thumbs up to the user.

This is the approach I have gone down so far:

1. Initialise the camera and set a preview callback

   ```
   _Camera = Android.Hardware.Camera.Open();          
   _Camera.SetPreviewCallback(this); 
   _Camera.StartPreview();
   ```
2. In the Callback, take the bytes representing the current frame and pass this as the input image bytes for Xamarin.Tesseract

   ```
   public void OnPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Android.Hardware.Camera camera)
   {        
   await _TesseractApi.SetImage(data); /// this hangs                
   string text = _Api.Text;
   return text;          
   }
   ```

This currently hangs when passing the byte[] into the Tesseract API. I'm pretty sure it's going to be because the Bytes in the array are either the wrong encoding, or, i'm fundamentally not understanding the Camera api!

Can anyone give me a nudge in the write direction?

Comment: it looks like Android returns a raw bitmap for the camera in the callback, and I would expect that Tesseract works with specific image formats

Comment: How did you achieve this without having memory issues ? I'm currently do the same but stuck at the moment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the code for [`TesseractApi.SetImage(byte[])`](https://github.com/halkar/Tesseract.Xamarin/blob/master/Tesseract.Droid/TesseractApi.cs#L59), it is calling `BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray()` which expects a valid Bitmap.

Unfortunately, the camera preview is returning a YUV image, which *BitmapFactory* doesn't support.

Here is code to transform the YUV image to a JPEG which you can then pass to Tesseract.

```c#
private byte[] ConvertYuvToJpeg(byte[] yuvData, Android.Hardware.Camera camera)
{
    var cameraParameters = camera.GetParameters();
    var width = cameraParameters.PreviewSize.Width;
    var height = cameraParameters.PreviewSize.Height;
    var yuv = new YuvImage(yuvData, cameraParameters.PreviewFormat, width, height, null);   
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    var quality = 80;   // adjust this as needed
    yuv.CompressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, width, height), quality, ms);
    var jpegData = ms.ToArray();

    return jpegData;
}
```

Comment: I am currently doing something similar, I'm my case I crop a section of the image stream of the camera and set that as the image of the tesseract to ensure I focus on the section necessary as well as a smaller image. The issue being face is 'Out of Memory' after about 15 to 20 seconds

Comment: @DrPatience - are you disposing of the MemoryStream?

Comment: Also you may want to reduce your sampling rate. By that I mean, if it takes a long time to process data input from a single frame, rather than attempting to process all frames, allow some frames to be discarded if too much work is building up.