# Capture camera live frame for OCR in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, ocr

I am implementing OCR in xamarin forms. I am using [TesseractApi](https://github.com/halkar/Tesseract.Xamarin) following [Tesseract OCR for Xamarin (part 1)](https://shamsutdinov.net/2015/07/01/tesseract-orc-xamarin-part-1/), [xocr](https://github.com/ThatCSharpGuy/xocr) and [MediaPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin). The implementation is straightforward from saved/captured image, but I am looking is to perform OCR from the frames not from the saved pic.

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (
                !CrossMedia.Current.IsPickPhotoSupported)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("No Upload", "Picking photo is not supported!", "OK");
                return;
            }

            if (!_tesseractApi.Initialized)
                await _tesseractApi.Init("eng");

            var photo = await TakePic(); //capture picture
           if (photo != null)
            {

                var tessResult = await _tesseractApi.SetImage(photo);

                if (tessResult)
                {
                    recognizedTextLabel.Text = _tesseractApi.Text;
                }
            }
        }

private async Task<Stream> TakePic()
        { 
            var file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync();

            if (file != null)
            {
                //show stream in image - this is for test only
                img.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
                {
                    return file.GetStream();
                });
                //return stream for ocr reading
                return file.GetStream();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Check the link below.                                                               https://github.com/xamarin/docs-archive/tree/master/Recipes/android/other_ux/textureview/display_a_stream_from_the_camera                              
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30920675/camera-preview-and-ocr